# How to store html in mysql database and retrieve it as html in nodejs app?

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

Suppose I store
`<b>bold text</b>` in mysql column then I should get it as **bold text**
And not as, `<b>bold text</b>`

I am using it in a nodejs app and using handlebars as view engine.

Answer (score 2):

To display html with your handlebars template, you'll need to use {{{variable}}} not {{variable}}   (replace 'variable' with your actual variable name.)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to inject a string into the DOM, you can do that pretty simply with innerHTML.

```
app.innerHTML = '<b>bold text</b>';
```

Comment: Actually I'm making a blog app. The blog body must contain html codes in order to format the page. My question is about that. I need to get the mysql data as text/html.